# Meaning of "private gentleman" in "The Worst Crime in the World"?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, g-k-chesterton, father-brown

In "[The Worst Crime in the World](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.528506/page/n203/mode/2up)" by G. K. Chesterton, Father Brown and his friend, a lawyer, was talking to a  rich old man who has lived alone in a castle for a long time, and who has just said that he will never talk to his son as long as he lives:

> The lawyer said: “Why, what on earth has he — — ”
>
> “I am **a private gentleman**,” said Musgrave, “as well as the custodian of a great inheritance. And my son did something so horrible that he has ceased to be — I will not say a gentleman — but even a human being. It is the worst crime in the world. Do you remember what Douglas said when Marmion, his guest, offered to shake hands with him?”
>
> “Yes,” said Father Brown.
>
> “‘My castles are **my king’s** alone, from turret to foundation stone,’” said Musgrave. “‘The hand of Douglas is his own.’”

I found that "private" may mean many things:

1. **living alone**: *And he was living alone indeed as I said*
2. **made his wealth independently**
3. **prefer the privacy**

I think that the third meaning is the most suitable in this context, isn't it?

And does "**my king's**" mean "**mine**", as I never met it before and can't find its meaning in any source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fourth position:  I do not hold a position of public trust.

As an official, it would be his duty to deal with odious people.  As a private individual, he has no such duty.

The reason why I think this likely is the anecdote about Douglas.  His castle was a public trust -- the king had installed him and his family in it, in return for his services as an earl -- but his hand was his own and therefore he could keep it private.

(That is what he meant by "the king's alone" -- it was, in reality, only the property of the king, he was just entrusted with it.  Bit of hyperbole in that, but a declaration of absolute loyalty.)

Comment: It could easily be number 3 - "I will not tell you what the reason is, because I value my privacy".